# Should I Inflate or <include /> a new layout on top of my main layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, include, layout-inflater

I am a bit confused regarding the rendering of other layouts inside my application's main layout.

I know inflate, which I use quite often, but a few days ago I came across `< include />` which can be used directly in the application's main xml layout, it quicker and cleaner.

like:

```
 <include
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        layout="@layout/titlebar" />
```

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: The same difference as doing something by code or in the layout. Mind that the included layout must be inserted in a `<merge />` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that one is done by in your code, the other one is done by Android. Include seems to be a good option, but it is even better in conjunction with `<merge>` as it does not require an additional ViewGroup thus making your UI faster when the measure pass is run. Read further [on the google's training website](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: `<merge />` works **together** with `<include />`. From the page you linked: `Now, when you include this layout in another layout (using the <include/> tag), the system ignores the <merge> element and places the two buttons directly in the layout, in place of the <include/> tag.`